# What is the meaning of "What are you supposed to be?"?

Tags: meaning

I am watching a TV show in which a girl visits her classmate's house. When she rings the bell, the classmate's mom thinks she's a trick or treater because it's Halloween. So she opens the door and says, "What are you supposed to be?" The girl says, " I am a friend of your daughter's."

What is the meaning here of "What are you supposed to be?"

Comment: Trick or treaters normally dress up as something, but it's not always obvious what they're supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

The mother was asking that girl that what her costume for Halloween is.

**What are you supposed to be?** = What are you dressed up as?